# Spring MVC Form - backing object has 150+ fields, possible to auto-generate the HTML form?

Tags: java, html, forms, spring-mvc

I have a java POJO that gets into my application and my database by someone calling an HTTP POST.  I want to display a webpage with a form that allows the user to edit all the fields of the object.

The 'traditional' way to do this is I make a JSP or something and manually put in JSP tags for each field I want the user to be able to edit on the webform.  The problem I have with this approach is that the POJO has about 150 fields.

Just like there are modern solutions where you pass in a java POJO and frameworks can generate JSON, or save it to a database, etc, 
**Is there a modern solution that will dynamically generate a webform based on my object, without having to maintain huge blocks of HTML/JSP/JSTL tags?**

Comment: Your POJO is *way* too big.

Comment: Thanks, let's pretend it has 2 fields then.